# Pass a jQuery loaded data to Google Charts API

Tags: jquery, google-visualization

I use the following script to load data from a form.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var str = $("form").serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            url : 'json.php',
            dataType : 'html',
            data: str,
            success: function(data) {
                var data1 = data
                $('#chart_div').text(data1) 
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

The `json.php` file prints the data in the json format that is required by google charts, ie:

```
{cols: [{id: '0', label: 'time', type: 'string'},{id: '0', label: 'Albania', type: 'number'}],rows:[{c:[{v: '1971'},{v: 2188650},]},{v: 3204284},]}]}
```

This script prints the data to the chart_div on the form page. But how do I pass the returned data to a google charts like so:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(data);
```

I've tried to put the whole google charts script in the success function, but this only makes the page to load forever without producing anything.

Comment: your JSON is not properly formatted, you can check it on http://jsonlint.com/  and here it produces error

Comment: Hello, the json is fine, I copied a chunk from the actual code which is huge, and there was probably some minor type error produced in the process. I've tested the code without the ajax, and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have to set the `dataType` as `json` to return the data into json format

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'GET',
    url : 'json.php',
    dataType : 'json',
    data: str,
    success: function(data){
    // data return the data in json format
    }
});
```

check the following from the link [ajax](http://stage.api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Ok, thank's for poitning this out, but It doesn't help in passing the returned data to google charts.